# Where can I find information on MSBuild:* as VS Custom Tool?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have seen `MSBuild:SomeTarget` used as `Custom Tool` in recent versions of Visual Studio (for example, [MSBuild:Compile slow save](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightdevtools/thread/a6cbbded-746b-41f9-8519-c09e0bd4dd01/)). However I can not find that documented anywhere.

Where can I find relevant documentation?

Comment: Chapter 4 in http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780735626287.do

Comment: Are you sure? Seems to be about Custom Tasks, not Custom Tools?